# ndb.get_multi(keys) returns an array of None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to get some data from the Google Appengine ndb.
I have the following code

```
keys = []
for field in self.request.arguments():
    keys.append(ndb.Key(models.MyModel, int(id)))

# Some unrelevant code

for k in keys:
    logging.info(k)

m = ndb.get_multi(keys)
for p in m:
    logging.info(p)
```

This gives me this output:

```
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,436 main.py:58] Key('MyModel', 42)
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,436 main.py:58] Key('MyModel', 44)
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,437 main.py:58] Key('MyModel', 42)
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,437 main.py:58] Key('MyModel', 43)
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,437 main.py:58] Key('MyModel', 44)
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,443 main.py:62] None
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,443 main.py:62] None
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,443 main.py:62] None
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,443 main.py:62] None
INFO     2012-09-07 13:18:23,444 main.py:62] None
```

I'm sure the models exist in the datastore with that id number. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id could be a string in your datastore. So Key('MyModel', '42') may be what you're looking for. Id's can be strings or integers. [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass) are the docs for further reading.

**Edit:**
Do your MyModel entities have parent keys? If yes, then you'd need to include the parent when constructing the key.

Comment: The same happens when I cast the id to a string instead of an int. (Except that it's surrounded by quotes of course)